# "Take a rest" or "have some rest"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, idioms, verbs

Which one of the these is the correct, or can I use both?

1. take a rest
2. have some rest

Or is there any better way to say that?

Comment: You can use both. What about them makes you think either is incorrect?

Comment: Maybe see [here](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=94833). Also, "get some rest" is much more common than "have some rest."

Comment: Although dictionaries define "rest" as countable, I find it an odd thing and would prefer "some rest" to "a rest". But again, I am not a native speaker.

Comment: Ngrams says that "get some rest" is [more American](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=get+some+rest%2Chave+a+rest&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3) and "have a rest" is [more British.](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=get+some+rest%2Chave+a+rest&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3) But everybody will understand both.

Comment: @Peter I'd say there's a slightly different meaning. 'Have a rest' seems more tailored-to-the-occasion, say after digging for 4 hours solid; 'get some rest' seems less localised: 'I've been doing 12-hour shifts for two weeks. I really need to get some rest.' Though I'm sure they're fairly interchangeable. **Ah** – I've just read Colin's and 200's answers.

Comment: Why randomly switch from ***a** rest* to ***some** rest*?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In my (UK) idiolect "have a rest" and "get some rest" are idiomatic, not the two phrases you give.

I find a slight difference in meaning. To me, "have a rest" is neutral: I am going to rest, with no implication about how much I need it.

"Get some rest" implies that I have a particular need for rest: either I have been short of rest recently, or some major activity is expected so that I need to be well-rested before it, or there is very little time available for resting, so I will avail myself of it.

Answer (score 15):

Common American English would use "take a break" or "get some rest", using "rest" as a noun. It is almost never used as "take a rest" by native English speakers in the USA. However, this phrase is very commonly taught to and used by EFL/ESL learners in Asia.

Answer (score 7):

I would never use *take a rest.* Rest itself means physically taking time relaxing, so I would rather use *rest* just as a verb.  And as a noun I would say *get some rest*.

Answer (score 6):

I would say "take a break" for a brief interval, and "get some rest" for a longer period.

Comment: Have a KitKat..

Answer (score 3):

To me (UK):

- **have a rest** is synonymous with **take a break**
- **get some rest** is synonymous with **get some sleep** (or at least try to sleep)

More formally, rest as a countable noun means "break"; whereas rest as an uncountable noun means "sleep".

Answer (score 0):

So to the people that say "have a break/rest"...Do you also say "I need to have a test" or "I need to take a test", or "I need a test"?
What about "I need to have a piss" vs. "I need to take a piss"?
"To take a 'noun' " in most locations is acceptable.

Comment: In my family, we *leave* a piss. And we don't want to know what you do with yours. ;-)

Comment: I hope you are joking. I've never been to any part of the world where people say "leave a piss" unless they are pointing out that the saying is a euphemism.

Comment: I don't see a euphemism there. A euphemism would mean changing *piss* to something more socially acceptable. And yes, that's what we say.

Comment: This is a comment (or possibly question), not an answer.

Answer (score -1):

the first one is similar to an order, the following one is like an obligation