# "use some rest" vs. "take some rest" vs. "get some rest"?

Tags: word-usage

> - use some rest
> - take some rest
> - get some rest

Which one is correct if I want to tell my friend to go to relax or take a nap? The phrase "take some rest" is familiar me but I also have heard "use some rest" from a movie.

Comment: In America, if you say "I could _use {some/a} rest" it means "I am tired and would like to rest." ////  If you say "I {need to/have to} get some rest.", it's the same, only more emphatic.//// In America, we seldom say  "take a rest" (although it is accepta ble grammar); more likely we say "_get_ some rest" or "_take_ a nap"

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Take a rest" or "have some rest"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52673/take-a-rest-or-have-some-rest)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"use some rest" is almost exclusively American.

> Example: I could use some rest.

"get some rest" is international.

> Example: I need to get some rest.

"take **some** rest" is unusual in my opinion, I would expect "take **a** rest".

> Example: I need to take a rest.

**NOTE**

You cannot swap 'use' and 'get' in the above sentences. They have different meanings. (see dictionaries for difference)

Answer (score 2):

The Ngram viewer shows "use some rest" as the least found, and it's almost always used with "*can*" or "*could*":

You look like hell; you *could* **use some rest**.

"Take some rest" is the next in popularity, and it's been with us for some time.  From [*Burton's Gentleman's Magazine and American Monthly Review*](https://books.google.com/books?id=rXJMAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA289&dq=%22take%20some%20rest%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAjgKahUKEwi9tcyi-onHAhXBbD4KHTHfABs#v=onepage&q=%22take%20some%20rest%22&f=false), Volume 3, 1838.

> Then turning to the Emperor he said "This is not a fit place for you. 
>   Go wasy. You are more ill than any of us ; go and **take some rest**."

The more usual idiomatic usage of "take" is to one's bed or a nap.

"Take" used to be more popular than "get," but around 1910 they switched places, and "get" is now about 30 times more prevalent than "take" in Ngram's sources.